# Definir propriedade com base em outras durante criação de objeto

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo uma tentativa de popular 'nomecompleto' com o resultado das duas primeiras variaveis, porém sem êxito.

```
var pessoa = { nome: "Joao", sobrenome: "Silva", nomecompleto : nome + sobrenome };

alert(pessoa.nomecompleto);
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: nome is not defined

Existe alguma forma de obter o resultado esperado da variável 'nomecompleto' na definição inicial da var 'pessoa'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conforme explicado pelo @Sergio, o objeto ainda não está construído na memória e, portanto, não há ponteiro para seu conteúdo ainda.

Caso seja realmente necessário fazer a declaração do atributo `nome_completo` dentro deste objeto literal (`{ ... }`), por exemplo: se você quer que, ao atualizar o `nome`, o `nome_completo` seja automaticamente "atualizado" junto, o mais próximo que se pode fazer é transformar o `nome_completo` em um método:

```
var pessoa = { nome: "Rui", sobrenome: "Pimentel", getNomeCompleto: function(){
    return this.nome + " " + this.sobrenome;
}};
```

**Disponibilizo aqui um [JSFiddle de exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/ruipimentel/5r7rxffk/).**

Answer (score 7):

Tem de fazer isso em passos.
Quando quer usar `nome + sobrenome` o objeto ainda não está defenido e essas propriedades ainda não existem. De qualquer maneira não seria possivel chamá-las assim. Desse modo o JavaScript pensa que são variáveis.

Use assim:

```
var pessoa = { nome: "Joao", sobrenome: "Silva" };
pessoa.nomecompleto = pessoa.nome + pessoa.sobrenome
alert(pessoa.nomecompleto);
```

Pode contudo fazer uma Classe e usar:

```
function Pessoa(nome, sobrenome) {
    this.nome= nome;
    this.sobrenome= sobrenome;
    this.nomeCompleto = this.nome + ', ' + this.sobrenome;
}

var novaPessoa = new Pessoa('Luis', 'Martins');
console.log(novaPessoa .nomeCompleto); // vai dar "Luis, Martins"
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/3epeLuzL/